# Multiple calls to DynamoDbAsyncTable.query and combine results

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Im using the JAVA Sdk
I’m trying to make multiple queries under one async dynamo table and combine all the results into one.

The query api uses the concept of reactive streams and I’m not able to find a way to combine results.

I would ideally want to be able to do something similar to

```
//call queries here
CompletableFuture<> allOf = CompletableFuture.allOf(queryFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));

allOf.thenRun(() -> {
 //aggregate results here
})
```

I have tried subscribing to the PagePublishers and pass a consumer where it appends the page items to a concurrent list. But I didn't want to go with this approach, I wanted something similar to what I described above